# Getting non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context error

Tags: java, arrays, static, inner-classes

I am studying inner classes in Java.There is an example of using inner classes with different access modifiers.I wrote the code just I see in the book but I get an error which I have mentioned at the title.As I know we cant use a static variable,method in a non-static scope but what I dont understand is I get this error only with my String array.Integer array works fine.What am I missing here?

```
package innerclasses;

public class AlanlaraErisim {

private class StringDiziYaz{

    private void diziYaz(String[]dizi){

        for(String x: dizi){

            System.out.println(x + " ");

        }

    }

}


protected class IntegerDiziYaz{

    protected void diziYaz(Integer[]dizi){

        for(Integer x: dizi){

            System.out.println(x + " ");

        }

    }

}



public static void main(String[] args) {

    AlanlaraErisim.StringDiziYaz stringDiziYaz = new AlanlaraErisim().new StringDiziYaz();

    String[] stringDizi = {"abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno"};
    StringDiziYaz.diziYaz(stringDizi);  //Gives the error

    AlanlaraErisim.IntegerDiziYaz integerDiziYaz = new AlanlaraErisim().new IntegerDiziYaz();

    Integer[] intDizi = {1,2,3,4,5,6};  
    integerDiziYaz.diziYaz(intDizi); //Works fine

}}
```

Thats the output:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - non-static method diziYaz(java.lang.String[]) cannot be referenced from a static context
>       at innerclasses.AlanlaraErisim.main(AlanlaraErisim.java:42)
>   /Users/sametsahin/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

Comment: Your variable name is `stringDiziYaz`, not `StringDiziYaz`.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that `diziYaz()` is an *object method* (non-static), so you cannot reference it from the class (`StringDiziYaz`). You must access it using an object of type `StringDiziYaz`.

If you change

```
StringDiziYaz.diziYaz(stringDizi);
```

to

```
stringDiziYaz.diziYaz(stringDizi); // capitalization of stringDiziYaz changed
```

then there should be no error. Perhaps you simply made a typo?